# Error trying to install opencv with python using homebrew?

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I am new to the world of computer visualization / programming, and I am attempting to install and run opencv with python. I have been following tutorials online, installed xCode, Homebrew, and the latest versions of python 2 and 3.

to install opencv, I entered:

```
=> make
```

and made it to 54% before I received errors of:

```
In file included from /Users/espeon/opencv_contrib/modules/text/src/erfilter.cpp:43:
/Users/espeon/opencv_contrib/modules/text/src/precomp.hpp:54:10: fatal error: 
      'tesseract/baseapi.h' file not found
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/text/CMakeFiles/opencv_text.dir/src/erfilter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/text/CMakeFiles/opencv_text.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I’m quite a newbie within this field so any suggestions would be appreciated!